# How can I get the last character in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

If I have the following variable in javascript

```
 var myString = "Test3";
```

what is the fastest way to parse out the "3" from this string **that works in all browsers (back to IE6**)

Comment: @Pekka -  i disagree,  there are 7 answers here and most of them are incorrect as they don't work in all browsers.  Not as simple as it seems.

Comment: Here's a [speed comparison](https://jsben.ch/BhZiB) of different methods. Usually either `.substr( -1 )` or `.splice( -1 )` wins, but even the usually slowest `.split( ' ' ).pop( )` won one time for me.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Since in Javascript a string is a char array, you can access the last character by the length of the string.

```
var lastChar = myString[myString.length -1];
```

Comment: Nice—and this is slightly faster. See http://jsperf.com/get-last-character-from-string

Comment: Note: this was introduced in es5, so not supported in very old browsers, eg. **IE6**.

Comment: **IE6** - 23 Feb 2017 - seriously?

Comment: It's not going to work in Mosaic either, just an FYI ;) To be fair, the question does specify they are looking for IE6 compatibility, so a note to avoid any confusion for any JavaScript archaeologists out there is perhaps apt.

Comment: what is the string contains spaces? When I use trim I got undefined @Jamie Dixon

Comment: @KhaledRamadan Can you provide a more explicit example that demonstrates the problem you're having please?

Comment: @JamieDixon Checkout the following please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523872/getting-the-last-character-of-a-string-is-not-working-after-trim

Comment: @KhaledRamadan It seems like the answer in the linked question is fine. Is there something I can help you with?

Comment: @JamieDixon Nop Thank you :)

Comment: Here's a [speed comparison](https://jsben.ch/BhZiB) of different methods. Usually either `.substr( -1 )` or `.splice( -1 )` wins, but even the usually slowest `.split( ' ' ).pop( )` won one time for me.

Answer (score 114):

It does it:

```
myString.substr(-1);
```

This returns a substring of myString starting at one character from the end: the last character.

This also works:

```
myString.charAt(myString.length-1);
```

And this too:

```
myString.slice(-1);
```

Comment: substr doesn't seem to be supported in Internet Explorer

Comment: do you agree that this doesn't work in IE6 7?

Comment: @leora IE can't handle negative values in `substr` according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Comment: **Better `slice`**. As `String.prototype.substr(…)` is not strictly deprecated (as in "removed from the Web standards"), it is considered a **legacy function** and should be avoided when possible. It is not part of the core JavaScript language and may be removed in the future. If at all possible, use the substring() method instead. - From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: Here's a [speed comparison](https://jsben.ch/BhZiB) of different methods. Usually either `.substr( -1 )` or `.splice( -1 )` wins, but even the usually slowest `.split( ' ' ).pop( )` won one time for me.

Answer (score 6):

```
 var myString = "Test3";
 alert(myString[myString.length-1])
```

here is a simple fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/MZEqD/

Comment: This is the only answer that utilizes the fact that a string is an array of characters

Answer (score 6):

Javascript strings have a `length` property that will tell you the length of the string.

Then all you have to do is use the `substr()` function to get the last character:

```
var myString = "Test3";
var lastChar = myString.substr(myString.length - 1);
```

edit: yes, or use the array notation as the other posts before me have done.

[Lots of String functions explained here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/string.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

```
myString.substring(str.length,str.length-1)
```

You should be able to do something like the above - which will get the last character

Comment: I had to get last `10` characters and it worked for me `myString.substring(str.length,str.length-10)`. Thanks buddy!

Comment: @hmd I think you mean:
`myString.substring(str.length-10,str.length)`

Comment: @DanSalo `myString.substring(myString.length,myString.length-10)` or `myString.substring(myString.length-10, myString.length)` both returns the same results. Last 10 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `charAt` method. This function accepts one argument: The index of the character.

```
var lastCHar = myString.charAt(myString.length-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at charAt function and take length of the string.

```
var b = 'I am a JavaScript hacker.';
console.log(b.charAt(b.length-1));
```